# Images added using QStyleSheet becomes blur/aliased in PyQt5 Python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pyqt5, qtstylesheets, qpushbutton

I am using Qt5ct Version 5.11.3 on Raspberry Pi 4 (Debian Buster / Linux). I have used border-image in SetStyleSheet to add an image as the background of QPushButton from the resource file (.qrc converted to .py). The images become aliased and square edged as shown in the picture below.

[image]

The images I have used are of high DPI 4800x4800 pixels. I have also tried to reduce the pixels/DPI of images but they are still aliased. How can I make these background images look smoother. I am using 7-inch touch screen with 800x480 resolution.

Code for creating widgets/buttons :

```
self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(4, 130, 61, 61))
self.pushButton.setAutoFillBackground(False)
self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: gray;\n"
               "border-image: url(:/newPrefix/files (4)/hour_glass.png);")
self.pushButton.setText("")
self.pushButton.setFlat(False)
self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
```

Comment: 4800x4800 to 61x61 is a ***huge*** difference, having an image that big is completely pointless for a button that small, and even good scaling algorithms can have problems with ratios that big and images with pure straight lines. You should resize them to a proper size (possibly a multiple integer factor of the [`iconSize()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#iconSize-prop)), using a graphics software and the correct algorithm (at least cubic resizing is required).

Comment: Thanks, @musicamante. I resized the icons (to 61x61 pixels) using Adobe Photoshop as smart objects and reloaded them using QStyleSheet. It worked. 
The images are not anti-aliased now but they are blurred. I think it's because of the low-resolution screen I am using.

Comment: That might depend on various aspects, and your code is too short to understand it. Are you adding those buttons to a layout (as you should, by the way)? If that's the case, `setGeometry` is useless, and the size will be completely decided by the layout manager. If you need a specific size, you must use `setFixedSize`. Note that this could or could not be the cause of the blurring, without a [mre] (including source images) it's impossible to give you a valid answer.